# Django query on decimal field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an object with a DecimalField value of 5.60.  I'm making a query:

```
Mdl.objects.get(speed__iexact="5.60")
```

This will return the correct result.  But this will not:

```
Mdl.objects.get(speed__iexact="5.6")
```

Is there a way to automatically reconcile this inconsistency?  The filter value is user provided, so I want to be sure that a user typing 5.6 can find the object.

Comment: Why are you using `iexact` for decimals in the first place?

Comment: because I don't know the answer to this question. :) What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`iexact` does an case-insensitive equality check, which is normally used for strings. For decimals with two decimal places, the Django database backend will probably store "5.60" as string for a `DecimalField`, so iexact-comparison with that will work because the strings are equal. But as you want to compare *numbers*, not strings, you should just use the normal equality operator.

```
from decimal import Decimal
Mdl.objects.get(speed=Decimal("5.6"))
```

Don't use strings, instead use the Python-builtin [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) type. When retrieving model instances with Django, you will get instances of that type anyway, so you should also assign this type in order to be consistent.

Comment: Although without the `iexact`, a string parameter will work fine: `Mdl.objects.get(speed="5.6")`

Comment: Right, for a `DecimalField`, strings and instances of `Decimal` don't make a difference.

Comment: Always pass a string to your Decimal, using a number will give you problems, even when setting precision: Doesn't work: decimal.Decimal(5.6). Works: decimal.Decimal('5.6').